# My favicon icon is not working in chrome?

Tags: html, favicon

```
<link rel=" shortcut icon" href="./img/favicon-96.png"/>
```

[image: This is my file list]

I wanted it to display on chrome but its not working i even cleared cache and restarted my pc even after this its not working!!

Comment: In Chrome Dev Tools look in the Network Tab and then hard refresh (Ctr+F5). What errors do you see for the favicon-96.png request?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below instead:

```
<link rel=" shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon-96.png"/>
```

Your file path had a period in the front when it didn't need one.

Comment: Thank you for your help the issue was that  in my original code was a space between the rel attribute and the attribute value. It was written as " shortcut icon" instead of "shortcut icon".Now i fixed it its working properly